# Python: como puedo sacar mensajes de progreso de un proceso en otra venta distinta a la de Tkinter que llama al proceso

Tags: python, tkinter, progressbar, python-3.7

soy novato en Python.

Necesito sacar mensajes de lo que está haciendo el proceso que es llamado desde una función desde la ventana principal en otra ventana Tkinter y no lo consigo. Cuando creo la ventana secundaria el proceso que se corre desde la ventana principal se para.

Por favor me podeis ayudar?
muchas gracias.

la función que pongo lee una tabla.
tiene un progressbar (barra_pg) que ignora mientras se completa el pintado en el grid y lo que empezara apuntarse antes del ejecutar el select se viese El Progreso y terminara cuando acabe el pintado en pantalla de los datos.
 intenté crear otra ventana que contenía solo el progressbar y cuando la segunda ventana coge el control con mainloop() el proceso de lectura se para.

seguro que es muy fácil pero no consigo averiguar como

def lee_db():

```
tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
Database()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM medios ORDER BY medio ASC")
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
encuentro = len(fetch)
salto = 99 / encuentro
for data in fetch:
    barra_pg.step(salto)
    tree.insert('', 'end', values=(data[0], data[1], data[2],data[3]))
cursor.close()
conn.close()
hoy      = datetime.now()
hora_hoy = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
hoys     =  hoy.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
literal  = str(encuentro) + ' datos ledidos de la Base de Datos a las:' + str(hora_hoy) 
txt_result.config(text=literal, fg="black")
```

Comment: Esa ventana secundaria ¿cómo la creas? ¿Será que lanzas en ella otro proceso vía `os.system()`?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Trata de agregar el código relevante de lo que estás intentando. Saludos

Comment: hola abulia. las salidas que hago por el terminal con print('estoy haciendo esto') son las que necesito sacar en una ventana secundaria mientas se están corriendo los procesos principales.

Comment: Sí, pero ¿cómo has intentado crear esa otra ventana secundaria cuando has observado que el proceso principal se para?

Comment: @antonioalonso Había editado tu pregunta para marcar el código con ``` que es como debe hacerse para que salga correctamente indentado ¿por qué has revertido la edición? Ahora se ve mal de nuevo